# MVC embed links on page from database

Tags: html, sql-server, model-view-controller, hyperlink

I'm trying to make a simple blog like page. And my main problem right now is that I want to be able to embed for example a youtube video. When the post loads from the database the link is displayed instead of being embedded.

Below is my partialView which displays my posts.

```
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Posts)
{
    <div class="posts">
        <p>
            <b>@item.Topic</b></p>
        <p>
            <@item.Text</p>
        <p>
            @item.PostDate - @item.Alias</p>
    </div>
    <hr />
}
```

the item.Text is where the embedded link is held. Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the Html helper:

```
@Html.Raw(item.Text)
```